# How to install Pipelight on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, pipelight

I am facing difficulty in installing pipelight in ubuntu 16.10,
As I can see [here](https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable), there is no release. Is there a way to install it.

Comment: Most likely you will be able to install the `xenial` version. But it may break some dependencies.

Comment: @Pilot6 but how to install the `xenial` version, please help me I don't know much about `linux`

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded on xenial using this guide: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

The release is there, pipelight-multi is probably aliased pipelight.

If silverlight 5.1 doesn't work, try 5.0. That one worked for me.

Don't forget to close firefox prior to starting.

After you're done with the guide run:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

Run firefox from terminal so you can see what went wrong in case your installation failed.